# How do I send same names with jQuery.ajax in specific order?

Tags: jquery

I need to create a `POST` request with `$.ajax` that would be the equivalent of submitting the following form:

```
    <form method="POST" action="test">
      <input name="foo" value="1">
      <input name="bar" value="2">
      <input name="foo" value="3">
      <input name="bar" value="4">
    </form>
```

In particular, I have values with same names, which need to be passed in the correct (possibly interleaving) order, so in the case of a `GET` request `foo=1&bar=2&foo=3&bar=3` would be correct and `foo=1&foo=3&bar=2&bar=3` would be incorrect.

I looked into the `traditional` setting, but I haven't managed to construct the `data` parameter correctly.

Currently, I am using `jquery_form` for such use cases, but I did not find any way to cancel the requests send by this and it still needs a `form`, which I sometimes create dynamically and remove it later again.

Is there a better way that creating the fully encoded body of the request manually? Maybe there is even a solution for requests that need `multipart/form-data` encoding without having to do the encoding manually?

Comment: I think I found a way in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5392344/sending-multipart-formdata-with-jquery-ajax, using `FormData`.

Comment: yes, `FormData` is your answer. so you could remove your question

Comment: As a side note to the issue, having your business logic require the request parameters to be in a specific order is a ***huge*** code smell. I'd ask why you feel you need this, and suggest you approach the problem in a different way so that this requirement can be removed.

Comment: That's a convention in the `Zope` framework. If a submitted name has the form `x.y:records` and occurs multiple times, it is collected into a list of dictionaries named `x` with key `y` on the server side. Whenever a name is encoundered that is already present in the current row, a new row is started. So it nicely matches the transfer of a table of input fields.

Comment: Regarding deleting the question: Even though there is another question which gave me the answer, it took quite a while to find it starting with the *ordering* requirement. I thought by answering my own question and linking to the original answer I could save someone else this time, but somehow klicking "Answer your Question" only creates a comment and not an actual answer...